# React Inline Style: How would I refactor this border style?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

This code works as I want it, but wondering how to refactor the border style.  I've tried it may different ways, but can't seem to get it to work without breaking up the border components into 3 separate parts. I'm setting the color through props because it's a dynamic component that can change colors to almost anything.

```
<div className="policy" style={{borderWidth: "1px", borderStyle: "solid", borderColor: this.props.color1}}>
     <h1 style={{ background: this.props.color1, color: this.props.color2}}>{this.props.policy}</h1>
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.contents }}></div>
</div>
```

I wanted something along these lines below, but I can't figure out the syntax or find any examples of it that work:

```
<div className="policy" style={{border: "1px solid this.props.color1}}>
     <h1 style={{ background: this.props.color1, color: this.props.color2}}>{this.props.policy}</h1>
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.contents }}></div>
</div>
```

I figured someone here would know. I couldn't get it to work through styled components either.

Comment: If only the color is a variable, why not put the rest in the class and only add borderColor style?

Comment: Are you *actually* using `styled-components` or just in-lining your style object? Why not something like `style={{ border: \`1px solid ${this.props.color}\`}}` using string templates? Can you share up your attempt at using `styled-components`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const PolicyWrapper = styled.div.attrs(() => ({
  className: 'policy',
}))`
  border: 1px solid ${props => props.color};
`;
```

[image: Edit styled-components styled wrapper]

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PolicyWrapper>Test</PolicyWrapper>
      <PolicyWrapper color="blue">Test</PolicyWrapper>
      <PolicyWrapper color="green">Test</PolicyWrapper>
      <PolicyWrapper color="red">Test</PolicyWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To be honest I vaguely recollect CSS shorthand notation not being compatible with inline style objects but I'm unable to locate any such documentation. I tried my suggestion from my comment and that doesn't work at all. I think you are stuck specifying the individual CSS rules or using a working styled-component.

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was trying to do in the first place and just could not get it.  This works perfectly.